# TriCheckbox in form?

Tags: forms, checkbox

I'm trying to make a form which allows TriCheckboxes.

For example, it starts out blank, when you click it, it gets ticked, if you click it again it becomes a cross, and if you click it a final time, it becomes blank again.

I've played around with javascript and classes and managed to get the graphics working, but how would I do so a TriCheckbox would work in a php form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but you can add `<input type="hidden" ... />` field and set its value in the `click` event handler.